# Regex for username with very specific rules

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I am not a regex ninja.  I've been tweaking this for an hour, and I'm sure someone on SO can do it more effectively.

This is a regex for a username with some slightly peculiar requirements (to accomodate legacy usernames).

Rules:

- length:  24 charaters maximum, 3 characters minimum
- must not start or end with a space
- any number of the following  (up to the max field lenght of 24):

  - 0-9
  - A-Z
  - a-z
  - .  (dot)
  - ' ' (space)
- zero or one of each from following set:

  - @  (at)
  - _  (underscore)
  - -  (hyphen)
  - '  (apostrophy)

Here's what I have so far:

```
^[^ ](?=[A-Za-z0-9. @_\-]{1,24}$)[a-zA-Z0-9_. ]*\.?[a-zA-Z0-9_]*[^ ]$
```

but it is not quite right.  I'm not sure how to escape the ' (apostrophe)

also, should I use another lookahead for the characters allowed zero or one times?

Thanks.

Update:
Note that target is the .Net 4.0 regex libraries with C#

Comment: You should really indicate what language you're implementing this in, the features of regex engines are so different. Also, do you mean "zero or one characters from the class `@_-'`" or "zero or one of each of the characters `@`, `_`, `-`, `'`"? (The scope of 'any' is ambiguous).

Comment: @LHMathies, Yes I see the ambiguity now.  I meant "zero or one of each from the set [@_-']"  so "a@_-'" is valid, but "abc@@" is not.  Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be a regex solution, decide on your own if this is readable/usable/maintainable for you.

```
(?!^.*?([@'_-]).*\1.*$)^(?! )[\w. @'-]{3,24}(?<! )$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2u4et)

`(?!^.*?([@'_-]).*\1.*$)` is a negative lookahead, if one of the characters you named is found it is put into capturing group 1 and to ensure this is not repeating using the backreference `\1`.

`^(?! )` is a negative lookahead to ensure there is no space after the start of the string.

`[\w. @'-]{3,24}` The characters you allow at least 3 at most 24 of them

`(?<! )$` is a negative lookbehind to ensure there is no space before the end of the string.

Comment: cool!  so close...  for [@'_-] they are allowed one (or zero) of each. (so "asdf@'_-a" is valid)

Comment: @DanO sorry, missed that one but fixed it now. I think then I need a negative lookahead for each of those characters that are not allowed to repeat. I updated also the Regexr link.

Comment: @stema,  Fantastic!  Thanks for the help.  My first time thinking through  a negative lookahead it definitely has its uses.

Comment: @DanO another update, found a solution that does not need to repeat the lookaheads at the beginning, using a backreference now.

Comment: @stema, Nice!  I must admit I am still parsing the syntax for that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You should not solve this problem with a single regexp, it makes the code hard to read and hard to modify. Write one function for each rule, then your check becomes very clear(not to mention for the maintainer)

```
if len(username) > = 3 && 
   len(username) < = 24 && 
   has_numbers(username) &&
   has_capital(username) ...
```

Did a test-implementation in python, just to verify my approach, can be found [here](http://git://gist.github.com/1058159.git)
(That was before you updated your question with target system ;-)

Comment: I fully agree with the principle behind this suggestion.  And I would have been done long ago simply coding it like you suggest, but with a regex I can store that in the config, and the customer can change their mind next week, it can change easily without a a re-compile, full regression test, etc.

Comment: @DanO fair enough, glad that we agree though on the general principle ;-)